# How to correctly filter an ID of an item to be able to update the data

Tags: node.js, api, express

I'm building a NodeJs/EpressJS API and I have an issue to complete my PUT method.
I would like to filter the Id of the product and update it. I'm not using Mongo but the persistent data is on a JSON file. Preferably I would like to make a custom Middleware but I stack on it and now I would like to understand how to make it correctly in my model then I will try the middleware.

the error I'm getting:

```
products.filter is not a function
```

The model:

```
// PUT Update the Product
const updateProduct = (id, newProduct) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        helper.mustBeInArray(products, id)
        .then(products => {
            console.log(products)
            const index = products.filter(
                product => {
                    return products.id === product.id
                }
            )
            id = { id: products.id }
            const date = {
                created_at: products.created_at,
                updated_at: helper.newDate()
            }
            products[index] = { ...id, ...date, ...newProduct }
            helper.writeJSONFile(writeFilePath, products)
            resolve(products[index])
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err))
    })
};
```

I tried to use a filter and find but not success and I would like to see the correct way of doing it.

The route:

```
// PUT Update the product
router.put("/:id", check.isValidId, check.updateProduct, async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    await product
        .updateProduct(id, req.body)
        .then(product =>
            res.json({
                message: `The product #${id} has been updated`,
                content: product
            })
        )
        .catch(err => {
            if (err.status) {
                res.status(err.status).json({ message: err.message });
            }
            res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
        });
});
```

Please comment if you need to see other parts I will update the post with your requests.

The full product model:

```
// Data Utilities
const f = require("../shared/utilitis")

// The data file JSON
const writeFilePath = f.productDir;

// We assign the data
let products = require(writeFilePath);

// We import the helpers as we need to interact with our data
const helper = require("../helpers/helper");

// GET All Products
const getAllProducts = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // Check if w have any products data
        if (products.length === 0) {
            reject({
                message: "no products available",
                status: 202
            });
        }
        resolve(products).catch(err => reject(err));
    });
};

// GET One Product
const getOneProduct = id => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // We use the helper to check the data is present in the array
        helper
            .mustBeInArray(products, id)
            .then(product => resolve(product))
            .catch(err => reject(err));
    });
};

// POST Create the Product
const createProduct = newProduct => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // We create new ID with helper
        const id = { id: helper.getNewId() };
        // We create a new date time with helper
        const date = {
            created_at: helper.newDate(),
            updated_at: helper.newDate()
        };
        // We build our query
        newProduct = { ...id, ...date, ...newProduct };
        // We add t the array
        products.push(newProduct);
        // Helper write to JSON the data to file
        helper.writeJSONFile(writeFilePath, products);
        // Resolve if ok Reject with error if wrong
        resolve(newProduct).catch(err => reject(err));
    });
};

// PUT Update the Product
const updateProduct = (id, newProduct) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        helper.mustBeInArray(products, id)
        .then(products => {
            console.log(products)
            const index = products.filter(
                product => {
                    return products.id === product.id
                }
            )
            id = { id: products.id }
            const date = {
                created_at: products.created_at,
                updated_at: helper.newDate()
            }
            products[index] = { ...id, ...date, ...newProduct }
            helper.writeJSONFile(writeFilePath, products)
            resolve(products[index])
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err))
    })
};

// Delete Product
const deleteProduct = id => {};

// Exporting the modules
module.exports = {
    getAllProducts,
    getOneProduct,
    createProduct,
    updateProduct,
    deleteProduct
};
```

EDIT
The JSON file as requested from comments

```
[
    {
        "id": "cace936d-b699-4f92-83da-b87e442f9ddc",
        "created_at": "Sun Dec 15 2019 18:51:55 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)",
        "updated_at": "Sun Dec 15 2019 18:51:55 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)",
        "name": "HP printer",
        "description": "A wonderful printer to print your amazing documents",
        "brand": "HP Printer",
        "imageUrl": "http://test.img",
        "price": 100,
        "category": "Printers"
    },
    {
        "id": "d5edc152-3910-4f79-a4cc-82e5a8428243",
        "created_at": "Mon Dec 16 2019 09:54:48 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)",
        "updated_at": "Mon Dec 16 2019 09:54:48 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)",
        "name": "Epson",
        "description": "Epson printer are excellent",
        "brand": "Epson",
        "imageUrl": "http://test.img",
        "price": 250,
        "category": "Printers"
    }
]
```

Comment: Where does the variable `products` in `updateProduct` come from?

Comment: I suppose from here `let products = require(writeFilePath);`

Comment: Can you share this file in the question? also try to run `console.log(typeof products);` and let me know what do you get.

Comment: Yes the file you mean the JSON file where I'm saving the data?
I will send you the result of the log

Comment: The result is `object`

Comment: @MEDZ I added the file into the post

Comment: It's weird that it's an object!! what happen when you log `products` itself?

Comment: I see one product

Comment: https://pastebin.com/d3vs4bX9 This is the log

Comment: that makes sense. you can not run filter on an object. It needs to be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you passed `products` in `.then((products) => {})` it overwritten the value of products that you required above. Also, `filter()` will not help you to find the index of element inside array, instead, you better use [`findIndex`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_findindex.asp). So, your code should be as follows:

```
const updateProduct = (id, newProduct) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        helper.mustBeInArray(products, id)
        .then(product => { //pass product as a result instead of products
            console.log(products); //now it should show the products array
            //the following returns the element that passes the check
            const index = products.findIndex((prod) => prod.id == id);
            let updateId = { id: product.id };
            const date = {
                created_at: product.created_at,
                updated_at: helper.newDate()
            }
            let updatedProduct = { ...products[index], ...newProduct}
            products[index] = { ...updateId, ...updatedProduct, ...date }
            helper.writeJSONFile(writeFilePath, products)
            resolve(products[index])
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err))
    })
};
```

Comment: I see thanks and this is the file you were commenting https://pastebin.com/Abdhs9ed

Comment: The issue is that you are using a lot of helper functions that I can not see it's implementation. So sorry for asking to see more files. But now i need to see `mustBeInArray` function

Comment: Yes no issue  appreciate the help I'm sharing my repo as it is open to see
https://cutt.ly/Rrqggft

Comment: Actually the last one helped me. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes but now it deletes all the other key values:
https://pastebin.com/utTnhpiF
I wanted to update just the name but the other values get deleted actually

Comment: Check my updated answer. Now i merge the current product with new submitted values. then added appended it to products.

Comment: That worked but there is a way to make it better like if I try to update with the same exact data to avoid that will start the writing instead show a message like nothing to update? For example, I put name = a and already name = a is present so instead to make the update to show like fields already present or exist? Hope you get my meaning is to save resources if no need to do it :)

Comment: Happy that it worked.On the other hand, You may need to create a separated function for that to each field inside the object since you can not compare the whole objects because even if every thing is the same `updated_at` will be different. You may exclude `updated_at` from both and give lodash package a try using _.isEqual(object, anotherObject) https://lodash.com/docs#isEqual